# How Do You Comment Out the */ Part of a Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, comments

I have preg_replace function that I'm calling and putting on multiple lines for readability but the `*/` characters in the regex mess up the comments. How can I comment out all these lines without moving them all onto one line?

```
return preg_replace('/.*/',
    'Lorem Ipsum' .
    'More Lorem Ipsum'
    ,
    $foo);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a different regex pattern delimiter character:

```
return preg_replace('#.*#',
    'Lorem Ipsum' .
    'More Lorem Ipsum'
    ,
    $foo);
```

**EDIT:**
The delimiter character is a feature of PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expresssion). No PHP configuration is needed to use a different delimiter.

[Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> ...you can use any pair of non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace characters
>   as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names
>   that contain "/", to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome).

[Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

> Non-bracketing delimiters use the same character fore and aft, but the
>   four sorts of ASCII brackets (round, angle, square, curly) all nest

These are all valid:

```
'/.*/'
'#.*#'
'{.*}' /* Note that '{.*{' would be incorrect. */
```

Take a look at [PHP's documentation on PCRE Patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to see a really good overview.

Comment: And php automatically detects the different delimiter character? Or do I have to set that somewhere?

Comment: I just updated the answer with more information to answer your question about the delimiter character.