# Comment a PHP line containing # / character

Tags: php

How do I comment out the below line of PHP code

```
$html = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $html);
```

Although the line can be disabled by something like

```
if (0==1)
    $html = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $html);
```

But still this is not a comment.

Comment: I think the `?>` is the issue as it thinks it's the end of the PHP code.

Comment: If you want to get it working till a proper answer comes, change the regex to `'#(<br */?\>\s*)+#i'` - think the `\>` fools it.

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with is stripping your regex pattern into it's own variable, then splitting this string using '`.`'. I was inspired by the following answer, which also suggests redoing the regex, but not sure if that is an option.

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498301/3324415

Sample:

```
/*

$pattern = "'#(<br *" . "/?>\s*)+#i'";

$html = preg_replace($pattern, '<br />', $html);

*/
```

Comment: I think you are missing some quotes in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ?> what @Nigel Ren mentioned in the comment.
The /? Pattern can be omitted because * this make it.

```
//$html = preg_replace('#(<br *>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $html);
```

The problem also occurs when strings like

```
$string = "?>xxxx";
```

should be commented out. In this case ? can to be replaced by \x3f (Note: In double quotes ! ).

```
$string = "\x3f>xxxx";
```

This is the same string for PHP, but is not an PHP end tag.